# Injection on ES6 classes constructors with Angular 1.X and WebPack not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm following this styleguide on a new project: https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide

So I created a module like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import { IndicatorSelectorComponent } from './indicatorSelector.component';
import { IndicatorSelectorService } from './indicatorSelector.service';
import './indicatorSelector.css';

export const IndicatorSelectorModule = angular
  .module('indicatorSelector', [])
  .component('indicatorSelector', IndicatorSelectorComponent)
  .service('IndicatorSelectorService',IndicatorSelectorService)
  .name;
```

Basically importing and registering on module the component and service.

Then created this basic component:

```
import templateUrl from './indicatorSelector.html';

export const IndicatorSelectorComponent = {
  templateUrl,
  controller: class IndicatorSelectorComponent {
    contructor($http,IndicatorSelectorService) {
      'ngInject';
      this.$http = $http;
      this.service = IndicatorSelectorService;
    }

    $onInit() {
      console.log(this.$http);
      console.log(this.service);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that both my injections ($http and IndicatorSelectorService) are not working... when logging on console they are undefined.

I suspect it has something to do with my WebPack process, so let me post the code here:

```
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import ngAnnotatePlugin from 'ng-annotate-webpack-plugin';

export default {
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    noInfo: false,
    entry: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/app.module')
    ],
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [

        // Runs ng-annotate on generated bundles
        new ngAnnotatePlugin({
            add: true
        }),

        // Inject implicit globals for jquery

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
        }),

        // Create HTML file that includes reference to bundled JS.
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
            inject: true
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/, loader: 'babel' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
            { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: "url?prefix=font/&limit=5000&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
            { test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'url?limit=1024&name=images/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.html$/, exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'), loader: 'ngtemplate!html' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Some one could point me what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any help!

/* EDIT */

In my bundle I have this being generated, so I guess it is being injected, but still don't work. Any clue?

```
var IndicatorSelectorComponent = exports.IndicatorSelectorComponent = {
  templateUrl: _indicatorSelector2.default,
  controller: function () {
    function IndicatorSelectorComponent() {
      _classCallCheck(this, IndicatorSelectorComponent);
    }

    _createClass(IndicatorSelectorComponent, [{
      key: "contructor",
      value: ["$http", function contructor($http) {
        "ngInject";

        this.$http = $http;
      }]
    }, {
      key: "$onInit",
      value: function $onInit() {
        console.log(this.$http);
      }
    }]);

    return IndicatorSelectorComponent;
  }()
};
```

Comment: console.log(this.$http);
      console.log(this.service);

     does it returns undefined?

Comment: Yes, it does. 
Thank you for the aswer.
I will check out yours webpack.config.js. I was trying to avoid using that way because with the way I was using I was not supposed to explicit inform every injection with $inject.
If the solution don't come up, I will probably change to the loader and use the way you do.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular 1.5 + webpack and I am also following that style guide. I am using `ng-annotate` to my loaders.

here is my `webpack.config.js` file.

https://gist.github.com/vistajess/7cf451471bd06dc1b636e81eaf15e7d6

sample angular service file.

https://gist.github.com/vistajess/d49090e538baca96d6a9c1f884a2cac6

Comment: you can also view my repo for angular es6 webpack starter as your guide :)

https://github.com/vistajess/angular-es6-webpack-starter